# AWS CLI vs Console - Cost Explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-billing

I'm finding that the AWS Cost Explorer Console and the AWS CLI Cost Explorer are giving two separate numbers. Any reason as to why this is happening?

**For example**:
From my console, you can see my total for Cloudtrail is $72.66

[image]

However, when I put these same exact metrics for CLI, my total is $72.04

[image]

I know this doesn't seem like a big difference, I'm only using Cloudtrail as an example, but some of my pricier services have bigger discrepancies. Is there a reason why this is the case / can something be done to make the console and CLI have matching monthly costs?

Comment: You have applied the `RECORD_TYPE` in the request JSON. So make sure you applied the same in  `Charge Type` filter in the console. You can find it on the right side `filters -> More filters`

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with multiple record type filters including without Credit + Refund but the Console price is always $72.66

Comment: If you download it as report in CSV, what is in it?

Comment: The excel sheet displays the following:
SERVICE             | CLOUDTRAIL($) | TOTAL COST ($)
SERVICE TOTAL | 72.65892             | 72.65892
4/1/2020               | 72.65892             | 72.65892

Comment: Try setting the `--time-period` `End=2020-05-01` in your script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage.html#options), you have to add 1 extra day on your end date. So in your case, you need to get the report for the month of April (from 2020-04-01 to 2020-04-30). Now you have to add an additional 1 day to end date which will be 2020-05-01.

> Sets the start and end dates for retrieving AWS costs. The start date is inclusive, but the end date is exclusive. For example, if start is 2017-01-01 and end is 2017-05-01 , then the cost and usage data is retrieved from 2017-01-01 up to and including 2017-04-30 but not including 2017-05-01

So your time period argument will be like `--time-period Start=2020-04-01,End=2020-05-01`

Comment: It worked. My numbers are being represented accurately, thank you so much!

Comment: I had the same issue. Thanks.